# How to count the amount of times the answer a,b,c,d,e,f has been given?

Tags: php, html, count

I want to count the times I select a option. 
So how many times I selected A,B,C,D,E,F .

I tried doing some form of a count but that didn't work.

```
<form action="Antwoord.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="Naam" placeholder="Uw naam:">
<?php
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM  questionlist_choice WHERE Qid='1'";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $i = 0;
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$vraag = $row['Vraag'];
$vraagA = $row['Vraag_keuzeA'];
$vraagB = $row['Vraag_keuzeB'];
$vraagC = $row['Vraag_keuzeC'];
$vraagD = $row['Vraag_keuzeD'];
$vraagE = $row['Vraag_keuzeE'];
$vraagF = $row['Vraag_keuzeF'];
$kikio =  "<div>
     <br><p>$vraag</p>
     <input type='radio' name='q[$i]' value='A'required> $vraagA<br>
     <input type='radio' name='q[$i]' value='B'required> $vraagB<br>
     <input type='radio' name='q[$i]' value='C'required> $vraagC<br>
     <input type='radio' name='q[$i]' value='D'required> $vraagD<br>
     <input type='radio' name='q[$i]' value='E'required> $vraagE<br>
     <input type='radio' name='q[$i]' value='F'required> $vraagF<br>

 </div>";

 echo $kikio;
$i++;
  }
}

?>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

I expect a echo or something that shows me how many times A was selected B was selected and so on.

Comment: With this form you should end up with `$_POST['q']` as an array of `["A", "B", "A", "F", ...etc]`. You can use [`array_count_values($_POST['q']);`](https://www.php.net/array_count_values) to get the information you're looking for.

Comment: @rickdenhaan and how to echo that?

Comment: @rickdenhaan and its for after filling it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_count_values()`](https://www.php.net/array_count_values) to find out how many of each answer was provided:

```
$counts = array_count_values($_POST['q']);
// e.g.: ["A" => 2, "B" => 1, "F" => 1]
```

You can then echo the numbers for each answer by looking in the result:

```
echo "A was answered " . ($counts["A"] ?? 0) . " time(s)<br>";
echo "B was answered " . ($counts["B"] ?? 0) . " time(s)<br>";
echo "C was answered " . ($counts["C"] ?? 0) . " time(s)<br>";
echo "D was answered " . ($counts["D"] ?? 0) . " time(s)<br>";
echo "E was answered " . ($counts["E"] ?? 0) . " time(s)<br>";
echo "F was answered " . ($counts["F"] ?? 0) . " time(s)<br>";
```

If you only want to list the answers that were actually given, you can loop through the `$counts` array:

```
foreach ($counts as $answer => $count) {
    echo $answer . " was answered " . $count . " time(s)<br>";
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with // e.g.: ["A" => 2, "B" => 1, "F" => 1]

Comment: That's just an example of what `$counts` will look like if you have four questions in your form and the user answered A twice, B once and F once.